# Passing mutliple query params not working Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpParams} from "@angular/common/http";

export interface Filter {
  countryCode?: string,
  postalCode?: string
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CountriesService{

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getCountries(filters: Filter) {
    const params = new HttpParams();

    if (filters.countryCode) params.append('countryCode', filters.countryCode);
    if (filters.postalCode) params.append('postalCode', filters.postalCode);

    return this.http.get('/api/countries', {params: params})
  }
}
```

I have an Angular 7 http service that fetches cities from an end point, I want to pass **optional** *multiple query params* to filter the results on the server side but it doesnt work however it works with just one param. These params are being ignored or not passed to the request.

Comment: should be `'/api/cities`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HttpParams is immutable as you can see here

https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpParams#description

To add multiple params you could do

```
  getCountries(filters: Filter) {
    let params = new HttpParams();

    if (filters.countryCode) {
      params = params.append('countryCode', filters.countryCode);
    }
    if (filters.postalCode) {
      params = params.append('postalCode', filters.postalCode);
    }

    return this.http.get('/api/countries', {params: params})
  }
```

Better than this, there is the param `fromObject` that you may use to make the code cleaner. Check it out:

```
  getCountries(filters: Filter) {
    // you need the '|| undefined' if the value could be empty string
    const paramsObj = {
       countryCode: filters.countryCode || undefined,
       postalCode: filters.postalCode || undefined
    };
    const params = new HttpParams({ fromObject: paramsObj });

    return this.http.get('/api/countries', { params })
  }
```

Comment: Thanks man it works, the fromObject is incredible, I ddn't know about it.

Comment: It is! Depending on your filter object you could simply use `new HttpParams({ fromObject: filters })` it helps a lot

Comment: Why they did like this. Previous version of URLsearchparams is far better than this. They are making more complications.